# Multi sql updates in a single database query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Is it possible in Mysql to turn this query into 1 query ?

```
UPDATE users SET users.title =1 WHERE  users.oldId =  'adab01' LIMIT 1 ; 
UPDATE users SET users.title =2 WHERE  users.oldId =  'agok01' LIMIT 1 ; 
UPDATE users SET users.title =1 WHERE  users.oldId =  'alla01' LIMIT 1 ; 
UPDATE users SET users.title =2 WHERE  users.oldId =  'allm01' LIMIT 1 ;
```

Something similar to this in SELECT :

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name,last_name) VALUES("John", "Doe"),("Jane", "Doe")
```

Is this doable in MySql ?

Just so you know what i was trying to do :

I was reading this article , Jump to (Avoid doing SQL queries within a loop)

http://code.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-php.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use a `CASE` statement to do this, and it won't be terribly pretty:

```
UPDATE USER SET USER.title = (CASE USER.oldId
                              WHEN 'adab01' THEN 1
                              WHEN 'agok01' THEN 2
                              WHEN 'alla01' THEN 1
                              WHEN 'allm01' THEN 2 
                              ELSE USER.oldID end)
WHERE USER.oldId in
(
    'adab01',
    'agok01',
    'alla01',
    'allm01'
)
```

Note that the `WHERE` is optional, as without it the data *shouldn't* be changed unnecessarily, but it will also "touch" every row in the table rather than only those that need updating.